# Ошибка во время обновления Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Во время обновления с 3.2 до 3.2.1 студия мне кинула ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот библиотека которую предлагают удалить:

```
lib/winp.x64.59DDBA6E777434D039AE09539E6AE899.dll
```

поиски в сети не дали результата, а удалять то что я не знаю не хочется. Может кто-то пытался уже обновится до последней версии Android Studio. Именно самой последней,а не последнего большого обновления. Просто может тут какие-то файлы они удалить пытаются, а они мне потом окажутся нужны.

Comment: В какой папке лежит этот файл?

Comment: не знаю) я в поиск вбивал и его не нашло